# How to uninstall default apps

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab, uninstallation

I wish to uninstall (or at least disable) some of the applications that the manufacturer installed on my Samsung Galaxy Tab computer. I tried Settings → Application manager → ALL, but is seems that none of the manufacturer-installed apps can be uninstalled (or disabled). How do I do this, please?

Comment: This site has answers for other devices, but I see nothing about this one.

Comment: It's the same for every device. You can't do it from the settings, and you need to be rooted.